# Jquery: Iterating over nested JSON with unique key names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach

I have a large list of objects inside JSON like this:

```
  var data = {
    4eae1aa12efa83745d00000b: {
        location: "office",
        latLong: [
            40.7069546, -74.0094471
        ],
    },
    4eae1aa12efa83745d000000: {
        location: "home",
        latLong: [
            42.3584308, -71.0597732
        ]
    }
  };
```

Where the `4eae1aa12efa83745d00000b` style key is random. How do I iterate through the JSON to print the location and latLong array of each nested JSON object?

I tried:

```
$.each(data, function() {
      $.each(this, function() {

        console.log(this.location);

      });
});
```

but that doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up the [$.map function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to translate the items in your object/array - Go for something like this:

```
$.map(data, function(val, i){

    console.log(val.location);
    console.log(val.latLong[1]);
    console.log(val.latLong[2]);

})
```

I believe that's what you're after anyway.

Comment: @christian.thomas `$.each` instead of `$.map`. To iterate over an array or object, use `$.each`. To replace the elements of an array / property values of an object, use `$.map`.

Comment: Either will work fine I guess, but you're right... $.each(data, function(val, i){
  
  console.log(data[val].location);
  console.log(data[val].latLong[0]);
  console.log(data[val].latLong[1]);
  
 })

Comment: Map is definitely more for mutating values in a list. If the return value is not used, then each makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your only problem is that you don't need the inner loop.

```
$.each(data, function(id, value) {
    console.log(value.location);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to loop over the properties of an object. To do this:

```
for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        // do something with obj[prop].latLng
}
```

.